# operator < cannot be applied to java

Tags: java

As below I've typed **javac App.java** on mac Terminal and I see **operator** five errors, all are the same. I'm not sure how to fix it as below and I appreciate your pointers?

I've import javabook.*; and this is JAVA code on Textpad.

```
import javabook.*;              
//import java.util.Scanner;         

class App
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        //declare variable
        String theNumber;

        //declare object
        Scanner someInput;

        //input
        System.out.println("Please enter area size : ");
        someInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        theNumber = someInput.nextLine();

        //processing

        if ( theNumber < 20 )
        {
            System.out.println( "It is too small." ) ;
        }
        else if ( theNumber > 20 && theNumber < 40 )
        {
            System.out.println( "It is perfect size." ) ;
        }

        else if ( theNumber > 40 && theNumber < 60 )
        {
            System.out.println( "It is too big." ) ;
        }

        //close the program without error
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Terminal response as **App.java:28: operator < cannot be applied to java.lang.String,int
        if ( theNumber < 20 )**

I would appreciate your help?

UPDATED:

```
import javabook.*;              //Same result Scanner or javabook. Tried both and it worked.
import java.util.Scanner;       //this is required

class App
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        //declare variable
        //String theNumber;
        //int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(someInput.nextLine());

        int theNumber; //need to convert your string theNumber to an int first. If you search for that, you'll find lots, both here and on the internet generally.
        int a = Integer.parseInt(theNumber);
        //theNumber = someInput.nextInt(); //this is commented out so now down to two errors

        //declare object
        Scanner someInput;

        //input
        System.out.println("Please enter area size : ");
        someInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        theNumber = someInput.nextLine();

        //processing

        if ( theNumber < 20 )
        {
            System.out.println( "It is too small." ) ;
        }
        else if ( theNumber > 20 && theNumber < 40 )
        {
            System.out.println( "It is perfect size." ) ;
        }

        else if ( theNumber > 40 && theNumber < 60 )
        {
            System.out.println( "It is too big." ) ;
        }

        //close the program without error
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"string" < 42` is invalid (`theNumber` is a `String` variable).

Comment: Exactly as it says: How do you compare a string, like `abdskjh` with 20?? You need to transform your string into a number type first (an `int` or `double` for example).

Comment: Sorry, an oversight, its now removed.

Comment: @pad it could fail if user enters something different to an int.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why is you are storing "theNumber" as a String and then trying to use integral comparisons on it. It is not an integer, and thus an error is occuring.

Instead, the following would work:

```
int theNumber;

theNumber = someInput.nextInt();
```

Now, you are storing theNumber as an Integer and you are using the scanner to read the next integer in and store it in theNumber.

Alternatively, you could continue to use the String and simply wrap it with `Integer.parseInt()` in your `if/else` statements, but given your code storing it as an `int` seems far more constructive.

**Note that now the code is checking that the user input is an integer. If it is not, an error will be thrown.**

**Edit - Note, the Scanner class must be imported (as in the code provided by OP it is currently commented out.**

Comment: Thanks it is now down to 3 errors as below:

Comment: App.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable someInput
location: class App
  theNumber = someInput.nextInt();
              ^

Comment: App.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Scanner
location: class App
  Scanner someInput;

Comment: App.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Scanner
location: class App
  someInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                  ^

Comment: @Irishgirl You should learn to read this error messages, otherwise I can tell you that you will be all the day here asking questions.

Comment: @Irishgirl: I've just noticed in the code that you posted you commented out your Scanner import. That has to be in - you must import the scanner class to use it. As ZouZou said as well, read the error messages carefully, they tell you what to do.

Comment: @Irishgirl: Does it work for you now?

Comment: @Andrew Martin. It is now two errors with scanner uncommented.

Comment: Error one: App.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method parseInt(int)
location: class java.lang.Integer
  int a = Integer.parseInt(theNumber);

Comment: Error two: App.java:29: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
        theNumber = someInput.nextLine();

Comment: You don't need to use parseInt() - that was just an alternative explanation instead of using an int. Just uncomment Scanner and use the two lines I provided in my answer and it will work.

Comment: @Andrew Martin. Which one: Scanner someInput; or import java.util.Scanner; I've tried both, both threw 3 and 3 errors respectively. See updated java on top of the page above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30434/discussion-between-andrew-martin-and-irishgirl)

Comment: Excellent response all of the above and I really appreciate it, Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

The error message for this is pretty explanatory.

```
operator < cannot be applied to java.lang.String,int
```

This is saying that the Java operator '<' (less than), can't be applied to (used to compare) String and an int.

So you are trying to ask, is "400" < 20, which you can't do in Java. You'd need to convert your string `theNumber` to an int first. If you search for that, you'll find lots, both here and on the internet generally.

Comment: You can convert it using [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the String to Integer

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(theNumber);
```

Basic rule in Java is that a condition must evaluate to boolean which means if(integer) is wrong

Answer (score 1):

`<` operator cannot be used for String values. `theNumber` is taking String value. Parse `theNumber` to int and then apply `<` operator.

```
int parseTheNumber = Integer.parseInt(theNumber);
```

Check the api [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)